# How does Ruby know which OLE object is enumerable?

Tags: ruby, enumerable, win32ole

I was working with Ruby and WIN32OLE (which is specifically, Excel).

I found all those enumerable objects, such as Range.Columns, are automatically enumerable in Ruby, and can be iterated using obj.each method.

I am wondering how it works? I understand that if you want to make something enumerable, you have to `include "Enumerable"`. But apparently they cannot put that line in the OLE object. Is it just directly mapping `obj.each` method to `for each` loop?

Comment: Check the source code. They probably inherit from a base object that includes Enumerable.

Comment: You may want to try `obj.class.ancestors` to see what class the object is, and what ancestors it has.

Comment: The ancestors of `Columns` collection are: [WIN32OLE, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]. It is the same for `Excel.Application`. But `Columns` is enumerable while `Excel.Application` cannot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's [an interesting set of posts here](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/82687) that might answer your question, specifically:

> (...) each is called as
>   dynamically as any other OLE method; it's not determined before the
>   call whether or not the object actually implements IEnum.

and:

> Enumerable#find method clashes the 'find' method of Excel Range
>   object. This is the (only) reason why WIN32OLE does not include
>   Enumerable.
>
> WIN32OLE class has 'each' method (WIN32OLE#each is defined) (...)

Hope this helps!

Comment: What about calling `.to_enum` on a WIN32OLE object to get access to all of the `Enumerable` goodies without risking the collisions?